# Select ONE image from list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple script that displays 2 blocks. You can click them and they highlight.

I'd like to force this so the user can only select ONE block at any time.

How do I achieve this?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/v36b3s25/

```js
$(".option").on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('option optionActive');
});
```

```css
.option, .optionActive {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.optionActive .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.optionActive .after {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude current element using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and remove the class from other `options` elements

```js
$(".option").on('click', function() {
  $(".option").not(this).removeClass('optionActive');
  $(this).toggleClass('optionActive');
});
```

```css
.option,
.optionActive {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.optionActive .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.optionActive .after {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @satpal - it worked beautifully. `toggleClass` is a great thing to have,

Answer (score 1):

Use `siblings`

```js
$(".option").on('click',function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('option optionActive');
     $(this).toggleClass('option optionActive');
});
```

```css
.option, .optionActive {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.optionActive .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.optionActive .after {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this @Shree - I will review your solution right now :)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove class optionActive and then add class option to bring all options to default state except the clicke one.

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass("optionActive").addClass("option");
```

Check the code below:

```js
$(".option").on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("optionActive").addClass("option");
  $(this).toggleClass('option optionActive');
});
```

```css
.option,
.optionActive {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.optionActive .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.optionActive .after {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @void - thanks again for your assistance here. It's greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk \m/